# MySQL use case statement into stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I want to use `CASE` statement in a stored procedure for `IS NOT NULL` but I get error when I want to save that:

ERROR:

> MySQL said: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   'ELSE SET @v_delay:=0 END INSERT INTO `ts' at line 19

My stored procedure:

```
BEGIN

    DECLARE v_user_start_time INT UNSIGNED;
    DECLARE v_delay           INT(11);
    DECLARE v_pyear           INT UNSIGNED;
    DECLARE v_mounth          INT UNSIGNED;

    SET @v_pyear     = pyear    ( _datetime_in ) ;
    SET @v_mounth  = pmonth( _datetime_in );

    SET @v_user_start_time := (SELECT `start_time` FROM `tsms_range_time` WHERE `user_id` = _user_id);

    /* Check for first record today for calculate Delay*/
    SET @v_is_new := (SELECT id from `tsms_entry_exit` WHERE `datetime_in` = NOW() );
    /* calculate USER delay */
    CASE WHEN @v_is_new  IS NOT NULL 
            THEN 
                    SET @v_delay := SEC_TO_TIME (TIME_TO_SEC(_datetime_in) - TIME_TO_SEC(@v_user_start_time)) ;
            ELSE
                    SET @v_delay:=0;
    END CASE;

INSERT INTO `tsms_entry_exit` 
        (
            `user_id`,
            `datetime_in`,
            `datetime_out`,
            `delay`,
            `period`
        )
    VALUES
        (
           _user_id,
           _datetime_in,
           _datetime_out,
           @v_delay,
           CONCAT(@v_pyear, @v_mounth)
        );
        SELECT ROW_COUNT() AS 'Affected rows';
END
```

Comment: The backticks suggest MySQL so I'm removing the sql-server tag.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are better of using a `IF .. ELSE` construct here like below

```
IF(@v_is_new  IS NOT NULL) 
THEN 
SET @v_delay := SEC_TO_TIME (TIME_TO_SEC(_datetime_in) - TIME_TO_SEC(@v_user_start_time)) ;
ELSE
SET @v_delay:=0;
END IF;
```

You can do something like

```
SELECT @v_delay := CASE WHEN @v_is_new  IS NOT NULL THEN 
SEC_TO_TIME (TIME_TO_SEC(_datetime_in) - TIME_TO_SEC(@v_user_start_time)) 
ELSE 0 END;
```

Comment: this action is duplicate my Store procedure and i want to create function for that

Comment: i want to use `CASE` statement instead of `IF`

Comment: You can't use `CASE` to set multiple variables like the way you are trying. Way around is using `IF .. ELSE` construct.

Comment: `@v_delay` variable is single and i can use `CASE` statement. thats true? can you invite me to chat?

Comment: @TuxWorld, You can use `SELECT` with `CASE`. check edited answer.

Comment: @TuxWorld, did the answer helped. If yes, then accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `case` statement is not control flow logic for stored procedure code.  It is logic used in a query.  The `if` statement is control flow logic.  You can do what you want as:

```
SET @v_delay = (CASE WHEN @v_is_new
                     THEN SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(_datetime_in) - TIME_TO_SEC(@v_user_start_time))
                     ELSE 0
                 END)
```

Also note some other errors:

- `SET` uses just `=` and not `:=`.
- You don't want spaces after function names.